# How to find module for a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Multiple times I've tried finding the right module to import into Powershell to get certain cmdlets, but I could not figure it out. Currently I'm looking for: `Add-MailboxFolderPermission`

I've tried the following which returns no results:
`Find-Command -Name Add-MailboxFolderPermission`

When I get the module name I want to install it using the `Install-Module "module name"` cmdlet.

Comment: do a search in your fave search engine for the cmdlet ... and it will get you to the MSDocs site. the page will list the module that contains the cmdlet. [*grin*] that won't work well in a script, tho.

Comment: Unfortunately lots of modules are not available through the public repositories but only as part of something installed with a product (like the Exchange cmdlet you refer to, which needs the Exchange management tools). If the module is already installed on a machine you can simply start using the command and PowerShell will auto-find the module and load it, but if it's not installed *and* not available publicly you're simply out of luck.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey thank you. I've tried that. Though with this command, on top of the MSDocs page is a link to the module "exchange", which leads to 404 not found.. So I guess finding the right module is simply tricky? 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/?view=exchange-ps

Comment: @JeroenMostert thank you.

Comment: @AterCZ - ah! i totally misunderstood your intent. [*blush*] it looks like `Scepticalist` has the answer to your actual question ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Install the Exchange Management Tools from the Exchange installation media

The command will then be available as part of the Exchange module

Answer (score 0):

from cmd cd to the installation media then run:

```
setup.exe /mode:install /role:mt /IAcceptExchangeServerLicenseTerms.
```

This will install the management tools.

Note: you may need some prerequisites, but if the installation fails it will generally tell you what it needs.  IIS management tools come to mind.

The Exchange Management Shell (ESM) always uses PowerShell implicit remoting to build local proxy functions.  They do this so they can enforce role based access control, but it also means it doesn't load like a typical module.

Aside from launching the shortcut there are a few ways to load the ESM :

```
. 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\RemoteExchange.ps1'
. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\CommonConnectFunctions.ps1"
. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\bin\ConnectFunctions.ps1"
Connect-ExchangeServer -auto -AllowClobber
```

This is for Exchange 2013 I presume 16 & 19 are similar.

I prefer this approach, it's more native, and in my experience more reliable.  If you dig through how the EMS shortcut launches it does exactly the same thing.

You can also add the snapin like below but again I don't usually do that.  However, it will often be the answer given in the Internet:

```
add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010
```

If you don't want to or can't install the management tools a 3rd approach is to use implicit remoting directly like:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ConnectionUri "http://<serverName>/powershell" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session
```

This is really cool, but the down side is the objects returned as string based objects.  For interactive use this is usually ok but for scripting or any time you're relying on on a specific object structure it could be a problem.

One last thing: some cmdlets may not be available if the user account doesn't have RBAC access to them.  If you are in the organizational management role group you generally don't have to worry.  But if a specific cmdlet is missing even though you've loaded up the shell RBAC is the place to look.

Sorry if I over-killed it, Let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange was Microsoft's first product with PowerShell support so they did some strange things with how their distributed the module.

With that said, they have a modern approach now in beta:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/exchange-online-powershell-v2/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps
that contains new, improved commands for Exchange Online as well as contains a backwards compatibility version of all the old commands.  This module can be installed from the standard, common, public PowerShell repository.